# Apple Script - How to I append the clipboard with formatting preserved to a note in Apple Notes?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, macos-catalina

I've created a script that appends whatever's on my clipboard to an Apple note. However, the formatting of the appended text is not preserved, not even the line formatting. **How to I append the clipboard to the note while preserving the *LINE* formatting of the clipboard?** I don't care as much about the other formatting, although it would be nice to preserve it if possible.

Also, I would like the text to be appended as a new line with a line break in between the pre-existing and appended text, and the text size of the entire note—including the pre-existing and appended text—to be 18 points.

```
set AppendText to (the clipboard)


tell application "Notes"
    tell account "iCloud"
        tell folder "Clipboard"
            set OriginalText to the body of note 1 -- the contents of the notes are encoded in HTML
        end tell
    end tell
end tell



tell application "Notes"
    tell account "iCloud"
        tell folder "Clipboard"
            set body of note 1 to {"<div style=\"font-size: 18px\">" & OriginalText & "<br>" & AppendText & "</div>"}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Suppose that the pre-existing text of the note is

```
Original text line 1

Original text line 2

Original text line 3
```

and that the text that needs to be appended is

```
Append text line 1

Append text line 2

Append text line 3
```

---

When I run the script the text of the note is set to

```
Original text line 1

Original text line 2

Original text line 3

Append text line 1 Append text line 2 Append text line 3
```

Whereas I want it to be

```
Original text line 1

Original text line 2

Original text line 3

Append text line 1

Append text line 2

Append text line 3
```

Comment: Copy and paste?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. Can you be more specific? @matt

Comment: Your example works for me using plain text - what is the formatting on the clipboard?

Comment: The formatting of the clipboard will be plain text—but, as far as I understand, even plain text contains line formatting. For example, if I copy any text to the clipboard with line formatting (e.g., line breaks, new lines) and then run the script `display dialog (the clipboard) as text`, the dialog will show the text with the line formatting preserved. However, my main script in the question above does not preserve the line formatting. **How do I preserve the line formatting of the clipboard when I append it to the note?** @red_menace

Comment: I updated my question; hopefully, it's more clear now. Thanks for all the help so far, though. @red_menace

Answer (score 0):

Since the body of the note is HTML, one solution would be to use the `textutil` utility to convert the append text before adding (the Notes application handles merging the HTML), for example:

```
set appendText to (the clipboard)

set convertedText to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of appendText & " | textutil -convert html -excludedelements '(p)' -stdin -stdout")

tell application "Notes"
    tell folder "Whatever" -- example
        set originalText to body of note 1
        set body of note 1 to originalText & convertedText
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I just tried that, but for some strange reason, the line breaks in the appended text get duplicated so that there's two line breaks where there should be one. Any idea why? @red_menace

Comment: Each line gets a line break - is there an extra blank line in between?

Comment: Nope. Try it yourself. More specifically, try running the shortcut multiple times without changing what's in your clipboard. Also, make sure that the text of the original note and the text that you copy have line breaks. Let me know if you get the same issue. @red_menace

Comment: I tested it before posting, using both plain and rich text.  You can also set the append text to a string for testing, for example `"this is a test" & return & "this is a test" & return & "this is a test"`.

Comment: Something else to try would be to exclude paragraph tags, since that adds some spacing with blank lines.  I've updated my post to include that option.

Comment: How do I exclude paragraph tags?

Comment: `textutil` has an option to exclude tags; I updated my answer to have it exclude paragraph tags (p).

Comment: Because that might be why extra line breaks are being added. @red_menace

Comment: That fixed it! That must've been why extra line breaks were being added @red_menace

Comment: Now I've noticed that adding `& return &` in between the original and appended text doesn't created extra line breaks. If I exclude the `& return &` it will still append the text on the next line of the note. And, if I add `& return & return & return &` It will still append the next on the next line without any line breaks. Any idea why?

Comment: @Peter Schorn, you do not need to use @$user_name every time as the user is flagged if there is a comment to their post. For the line break between the original and converted text use `& "<br>" &` between them. Also the code of this answer does not fulfill your 18 points requirement mention in your OP.

Comment: You can add `-fontsize 18` to the `textutil` _command_, however that will only resize the `convertedText` not the `originalText` which he also wants set to 18 points.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to red_menace and user3439894, I've completed the script. Here it is.

```
set appendText to (the clipboard)

set convertedText to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of appendText & ¬
    " | textutil -convert html -fontsize 18 -excludedelements '(p)' -stdin -stdout")

tell application "Notes"
    tell account "iCloud"
        tell folder "Clipboard"
            set originalText to the body of note 1
            if originalText as string is "" then
                set body of note 1 to {"<div style=\"font-size: 18px\">" & convertedText & "</div>"}
            else
                set body of note 1 to {"<div style=\"font-size: 18px\">" & originalText & ¬
                    "</div><div><span style=\"font-size: 18px\"><br></span></div> <div style=\"font-size: 18px\">" & ¬
                    convertedText & "</div>"}
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks! That's much simpler. I'll use that.